# Prevent windows from assigning certain drive letters

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-8.1

After configuring our network to use certain drive letters, I bumped into a problem when at some times, some of our users plugs one or two USB disks to the computer before boot.

Windows then, ofcourse, detects the drive and assign F: and H: to these USB drives, where F should be a network share and H their home drive.

Is there any way I can make a registry change, a GPO or whatever, to make sure Windows does not use these drive letters to assign other drives than what I want them to be?

Preferred would be to simply lock the drive letters. A script running at login to reassign drive letters and network shares would be the least wanted solution.

Hope someone can help me!

Best regards
/Rickard

Comment: There is a reason for the convention of assigning network drive letters from Z upwards and local drives from C downwards...  Would it be possible to move the network drives to a less conflicting letter?

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue. [USB Drive Letter Manager](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) is a decent tool to use, it'll 'reserve' certain drive letters. Be aware that you do need to pay for commercial use. Otherwise, you might be able to do this with Powershell v3's [New-PSDrive -Persist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx) switch?